# "That which" or "What" for academic writing

Tags: word-choice, academic-writing

*That which* and *what* have equivalent meanings. Which is better to use in an academic context? Does it depend on the context, e.g. scientific report vs essay?

For example:

1. That which comes from the above area is green.
2. What comes from the above area is green.

Comment: It depends on the context of the _sentence_ you intend to put it in.

Comment: Is it equivalent to 'the one which comes ...' or 'material emanating ...'? If the latter, I'd change the style.

Comment: This doesn't seem to parse no matter which of those two is selected. It is not possible for **anything** to "come from the above the area". That's because the preposition *from* requires a noun phrase as its complement but   *the above the area* is not a noun phrase. It does not appear to be a syntactic constituent of any recognizable sort whatsoever.  You may wish to consider visiting our sister site for [ell.se].

Comment: Could it be that you meant _the above area_ and not _the above **the** area_?

Comment: @fev The "Tour" page doesn't give any info on how to ask good questions. Better to share the [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Also, you linked the Tour page for English Stack Exchange, not ELL

Comment: My fault. Deleted the comment.

Comment: I think you should say something like "Items which come from the above area are shown in green". It sounds more natural to be more specific, or include a placeholder like "things" or "items".

Comment: In academic writing, it's best not to start a sentence with that which or what. Green is what comes from above. Pa-lease.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question should have stayed on EL&U, it was actually a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210732/that-which-vs-what) whose answer, however, merely states that ***that which*** is formal, without providing a reference. And I don't blame the user, it is not easy to find such a reference.

I did manage to find a comment on this in the [CaGEL](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language), p. 1036. After providing two examples:

> - [i] It would mean abandoning ***that which*** we hold most dear. [antecedent + clause]
> - [ii] It would mean abandoning ***what*** we hold most dear. [fused relative]

It goes on to analyse them:

> These are syntactically equivalent (though ***[i] belongs to very formal style***). Syntactically, *that* in [i] is *antecedent*, with *which we hold most dear* an integrated relative clause modifying it, but in [ii] *what* corresponds to *that* and *which* combined, so that it is not possible to separately identify antecedent and relative clause - hence the term *fused*.

So there you go, this reputable source confirms that ***that which*** and ***what*** mean the same, but are syntactically different, and ***that which*** is very formal. As long as your text is formal, regardless of the field or type of writing, you can use it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are not good examples of how "that which" is used in academic writing.

"That which" is used as an abstract stand-in for "anything and everything", and the intention is to be as *broadly encompassing* as possible, as the clausal complement of "which" will define the salient feature(s).

Here's a definition, for example:

> Highway Litter: that which is lying scattered on the roadway proper or on the shoulder of the road; trash, refuse.

"that which" is used there to refer in the abstract to anything and everything that is lying scattered on the road or on the shoulder of the road, and that could be old mattresses, hubcaps, blown-out tractor-trailer tires, candy wrappers, soda cups, hamburger wrappers, plastic bags, newspapers, etc.

You only use "that which" when you need to be broadly encompassing and abstract.

"What" is somewhat informal.  If you know what the specific thing is, there's no need to use "what" unless you're aiming for a casual style.

> When the ocean temperature rises, what happens is ...

versus:

> When the ocean temperature rises, the amount of water in the atmosphere increases, the sea-level rises as a result of thermal expansion, ...